# how to fetch random numbers of rows from mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database

I have around 300 records in some table in mysql database. And I have a requirement to fetch 40 random records with one query. How to write the query?
need help
thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rand+mysql try looking into these topics. Your answer is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a small table likes yours it should suffice with this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 40;
```

Note that this is not suitable for large tables since MySQL will have to do a table scan and order all rows in the table due to the usage of `ORDER BY RAND()`. For large tables you will have to implement this mostly in application code, keeping track of which rows you've already got and generating random ids to fetch.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `rand()` with `order by` like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM tableName
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 40
```

Answer (score 1):

`order by rand()` may cause performance issue, instead try to do in following way:

```
 // what NOT to do:  
 $r = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");  

 // much better:  

 $r = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM user");  
 $d = mysql_fetch_row($r);  
 $rand = mt_rand(0,$d[0] - 1);  

  $r = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user LIMIT $rand, 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not a fast solution, but it works fine for just 300 records

```
SELECT [rows]
FROM [table]
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 40
```

Answer (score 0):

you should user `RAND()` in the `WHERE` clause

but you first make fragment  40 / number of rows in table

ex:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE RAND()< 0.0005;
```

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 40